# Calculate average, minimum, maximum interval between date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do this with SQL. I have a transaction table which contain `transaction_date`. After grouping by date, I got this list:

```
| transaction_date |
|    2019-03-01    |
|    2019-03-04    |
|    2019-03-05    |
|       ...        |
```

From these 3 transaction dates, I want to achieve:

- Average = ((4-1) + (5-4)) / 2 = 2 days (calculate DATEDIFF every single date)
- Minimum = 1 day
- Maximum = 3 days

Is there any good syntax? Before I iterate all of them using WHILE.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how the values (4-1) + (5-4)  are related  to your data sample  ???  ..and for the others  values???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mysql version didn't support `lag` or `lead` function.

You can try to make a column use a subquery to get next DateTime. then use  `DATEDIFF` to get the date gap in a subquery.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT avg(diffDt),min(diffDt),MAX(diffDt)
FROM (
  SELECT  DATEDIFF((SELECT transaction_date 
                            FROM  T tt
                            WHERE tt.transaction_date > t1.transaction_date
                            ORDER BY tt.transaction_date 
                            LIMIT 1
                           ),transaction_date) diffDt
  FROM T t1
) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d090e/5/0)**:

```
| avg(diffDt) | min(diffDt) | MAX(diffDt) |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|           2 |           1 |           3 |
```

if your mysql version higher than 8.0 you can try to use `LEAD` window function instead of subquery.

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT avg(diffDt),min(diffDt),MAX(diffDt)
FROM (
  SELECT  DATEDIFF(LEAD(transaction_date) OVER(ORDER BY transaction_date),transaction_date) diffDt
  FROM T t1
) t1;

| avg(diffDt) | min(diffDt) | MAX(diffDt) |
| ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 2           | 1           | 3           |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c3EvNDNN9w6huAEmw4Kw2/0)